# Историческая общность слов

Tags: морфемика, этимология, однокоренные-слова

Вопрос олимпиады для школьников: "Разделите слова на группы по исторической общности основ. Сколько групп у вас получилось?" Интересно, а как мы, взрослые, ответим?

Запонка, запинаться, путы, распять, вспять, пятка, пнуть, препинание, перепонка, пяльцы, пялиться, путать, попона,запятая, пята, пядь, пясть, запястье, пятый, пятница, пятьсот, пятно, опять, выпятить

Comment: А какие слова нужно разделить на группы? Какие-то конкретные из списка?

Comment: Не вызывают сомнения четыре ряда:

 1. Пятница (пятый день недели), пятьсот (пять сотен), пятый
 2. Пятка, пята (тоже самое).
 3. Пясть, запястье
 3. Пялиться, пяльцы (чем пялят).

Comment: Хотелось бы получить полный ответ

Comment: Давайте поразмышляем вместе.

Comment: Я уже поломала голову, поблуждала по этимологическим словарям,интересно получается, не нашла только попону. Думаю,всё-таки однокоренное к словам ПЕРЕПОНКА,ЗАПОНКА, ЗАПИНАТЬСЯ.Древнерусское перепона-покрывало, попона - тоже покрывало, только для лошади.Может, тоже однокоренные?

Comment: Думаю, да.

Comment: Людмила: "…не нашла только попону". === 

Из словаря Шелякина М.А. ("Объяснительный словарь непроверяемых орфограмм русского языка"):

ПОПОНА (образовано от * _попяти < пяти_ -- тянуть, крыть + приставка _по-_ в значении направленности действия на поверхность предмета; корневой вокализм отражает историческое чередование _о//е_: ср. др.-рус. _опона_ -- завеса, _пяти, пну, путо_  цепь)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос с подвохом. Предполагая, что на олимпиадах не дают словарей, вижу только одну надёжную зацепку - фонетическую (чтобы найти решение на основании анализа значений, нужны эрудиция и опыт, как минимум, [@tmp](/users/1170/tmp) :-) - вряд ли это есть у школьников).

На первый беглый взгляд, я бы разделил слова на следующие группы:

запинаться, распять, пнуть, препинание,

запонка, перепонка, попона,

путы, путать,

пяльцы, пялиться,

пядь, пясть, запястье,

вспять, пятка, запятая, пята, выпятить, пятый, пятница, пятьсот, пятно, опять

Comment: А вы уверны, что это олимпиада - очная и что словарей не дают?  
Фонетический подход вообще ненадежен, особенно если не знать общих принципов и путей исторического изменения фонетики.

Comment: сознании = создании

Comment: Олимпиада очная, но вопрос повышенной трудности (для талантливых ). Я бы в детстве точно на такой не ответила правильно, значит, не из талантливых. Мы вообще как-то историю языка в школе обошли, а теперь это есть в программе. Кто любознателен - знает. Ваш подход верен, этого от детей и ждали.

Comment: @Людмила, это вопрос для эрудированных. Ну, для любознательных, да. Но не для талантливых (это всё-таки разные вещи). Ответ, скорее всего, какой-нибудь "пограничный", допускает разные толкования.

Answer (score 1):

За исключением попоны (без словаря - вероятно родственное "перепонка", но не уверен) получилось две или три группы.

А.

1. пята, пятка, опять, пядь, пясть, запястье, вспять, выпятить, пятно, запятая, запонка, запинаться, препинание, перепонка, попона(?), путать, пнуть, путы (<?>)
2. распять, пяльцы, пялиться

Здеcь:

1. слова со значением "препятствие при движении", "задний" и проч. (путать, пинать, пятка) и
2. пялить, пялиться. Подозреваю, что они могут быть родственными через "распинать".

Б. пятый, пятница, пятьсот, (от индоевропейского pent, родственным предыдущим быть не может)

Это навскидку, без словарей действительно трудно.

А ответы есть?

**UPD** --------

Ах я идиот! Распятие - это же от слова "пять", пять частей - конечности и голова...)))
Всё, вопрос решен.

Comment: Ответы есть(без подробных объяснений), но не хотелось бы отнимать возможности у кого-то правильно ответить. Пока правильного ответа нет. Ближе всех к истине Вы.

Comment: Это понятно. Главное, что они есть в прниципе. И через какое-то время из можно будет увидеть.  
  
>Ближе всех к истине Вы.  
Неужели и "пять" родственно? Тогда это уже вопрос терминологии. Подозреваю, даже почти уверен, что в индоевропейском "пять" может быть родственно всему остальному через значение "рука" - "пясть" и "пять". Но в русский-то они попали явно разными путями... В таких случаях говорить о родственности в русском не принято.

Comment: Кстати, в словарях я всё нашла, кроме этой пресловутой попоны.Видимо, это из диалектов, древнерусский ведь весь из диалектов. Или и вовсе заимствованное. Но в тюркизмах тоже нет. Только догадываться можно.

Comment: Да, я видел про попону. Просто слово не на слуху, потому "на автопилоте" и этимология не всплывает. лет сто назад сомнений бы не было, уверен.   

//===========  

Я понял! "Hаспятие" - это же от "пять". Пять "конечностей", включая голову... Все, так что мне можно и в словарь смотреть.

Comment: Дурдом, честное слово. Мне нравится версия из [википедии][1]. Если смотреть с этой точки зрения, то распять - это значит распинать, т.е. пялить на крест...

> пять частей - конечности и голова...)))

не понял.

Пятно чисто гипотетически я бы вывел как след от пятки.

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D1%8B#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F

Comment: Ну так соберите вместе все Ваши догадки и ответьте, Вашего ответа пока нет, только комментарии.